# push_back a vector into another vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I want to `push_back()` a vector `M` into vector `N`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = -1;
    vector<vector<int> >N,
    vector<int>M;
    int temp;

    while (i++ != 5)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        N.push_back(temp);
    }

    N.push_back(vector<int>M);
    return 0;
}
```

### Compilation error

I get a syntax error.

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:28: error: invalid declarator before ‘M’
test.cpp:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::push_back(int&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:733: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >]
test.cpp:37: error: ‘M’ was not declared in this scope
coat@thlgood:~/Algorithm$
```

Comment: Let's give gentle suggestions for improvements to new community members.  I agree, error messages are helpful.

Comment: @Nicol: Yucoat has updated the question to include the error message. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
M.push_back(temp);
```

in the while loop, besides the invalid syntax pointed out in @StilesCrisis' answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
N.insert(N.end(),M.begin(),M.end());
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 6):

This line

```
N.push_back(vector<int>M);
```

should be

```
N.push_back(M);
```

Also

```
vector<vector<int> >N,
```

should be

```
vector<vector<int> >N;
```

Comment: I followed your advice and changed my code,but g++ still doesn't accept

Comment: @Yucoat Have you tried understanding the error messages g++ gives you?  It should be telling you there's an error inside your `while`

Answer (score 3):

You have few minor mistakes.

You could solve them by looking on each of the compilation errors you got, and thinking what it means. If the error is not clear, you can look at the error's line number, and think what could cause it.

See the working code:

```
int main()
{
    int i = -1;
    vector<vector<int> >N;
    vector<int>M;
    int temp;

    while (i++ != 5)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        M.push_back(temp);
    }

    N.push_back(M);
    return 0;
}
```